# Hacer Seeding de Un Json en Laravel

Tags: json, laravel-5, laravel

Desde laravel 5.3 se permite migraciones con json 
$table->json('links_normales');

Pero en el seed

```
DB::table('courses')->insert([
          'name' => 'Curso Nuevo',
          "links_normales": {
            "Opcion 1": "xd",
            "Opcion 2": "red"
          }
        ]);
```

Cuando intento hacer ese seed sale:
 syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ']'

El el factory tengo esto

```
$factory->define(App\Course::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
return [
    'name' => $faker->name,
    'links_normales' => $faker->name,
];
```

});

El problema esta en como agrego el json al seed

Answer (score 0):

La manera correcta seria asi:

```
DB::table('courses')->insert([
          'name' => 'Curso Nuevo',
          "links_normales": '{"Opcion 1": "xd","Opcion 2": "red"}'
        ]);
```